Vuetify 2 x Vue.js 2 - cannot show the expected value inputted in the text field
I have textfield that has auto word. This means that any letters or characters inputted in the textfield will automatically replaced.
As see in the textfield, you cannot freely type whatever the word you like because it is replaced to "This is automatic word. Any letters or character type in textfield will be replaced by this sentence."


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      automaticWord: "This is automatic word. Any letters or character type in textfield will be replaced by this sentence.",
      userInput: [],
      displayInput: "",
      result: '',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    updateInput() {
      //Store any character inputted in textfield.
      this.userInput.push(this.displayInput)
      
      //Replace any character inputted in textfield to automaticWord.
      this.displayInput = this.automaticWord.slice(0, this.displayInput.length);
    },
    showResult() {
      //Pass the complete word inputted in the textfield in result.
      this.result = this.userInput[this.userInput.length - 1].toString();
    },
  },
})
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-text-field
          label="Type here"
          v-model="displayInput"
          @input="updateInput"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="showResult">Show</v-btn>
        <div class="ma-3">
            Result: <span class="text-h6 red--text">{{ result }}<span>
        </div>
    </v-container>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>



My problem here is, I cannot get the correct value inputted from the textfield.
Example:
If you type "jump" in the textfield, it is automatically replace into "This"(shown in the texfield) which came from the automaticWord. Now, I want to show this inputted word "jump" when i click the Show button. But sadly, the result is wrong, as it shows "Thip" instead of "jump".
I wonder where my missing part here.
Thank you for your help.

I think you should use :value instead of v-model and get the inputed text from the event on the @input event handler.

@MarioSantini, Thank you, but it seems I already tried that :value and use @input="updateInput($event)", But the result I get is still the same(which is the wrong one).

Using the :value is the proper way to go here, and the problem in your code is that the value from the displayInput is overwritten by you except the last char. So you should change your code by getting the real DOM event and intercept the character inserted from the user, and save it. I'm not sure this is possible with v-text-field. Use displayInput just for what you want to show in the text field.

In your current code, you're overriding user input each time a character is added by copying displayInput in userInput. Therefore only last user inputted char is kept and previous ones are replaced by automaticword.
To solve this, you can use the fact that v-field will send its content to event callback. By doing this, you can handle separately the real user input and the displayed value. No need to use v-model, simply use :value property and let your callback do the job.
Aside this, you may also want to handle text pasting or character range selection deletion or replacement. A string diff between text field input and automatic word will do the trick. Eventually, you may want that any sentence that exceeds automatic words length to be truncated.


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      automaticWord: "This is automatic word. Any letters or character type in textfield will be replaced by this sentence.",
      userInput: '',
      displayInput: "",
      result: '',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    updateInput(input) {
      // we'll make a diff from automaticWord to extract "real" user input
      // This will handle paste and character range deletion and/or replacement
      let updated = ''
      
      for(let i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
        // Automatic word length reached. Block further processing
        if(this.automaticWord.length < i) {
          break
        }
        
        // Added characters case
        if(this.userInput[i] === undefined) {
          updated += input[i]
          continue
        }
        
        // Other cases
        if(input[i] === this.automaticWord[i]) {
          updated += this.userInput[i]
        } else {
          updated += input[i]
        }
      }
      
      this.userInput = updated
      
      // Replace the any character inputted in textfield to automaticWord.
      this.displayInput = this.automaticWord.slice(0, this.userInput.length);
    },
    showResult() {
      // Pass the complete word inputted in the textfield in result.
      this.result = this.userInput;
    },
  },
})
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-text-field
          label="Type here"
          :value="displayInput"
          @input="updateInput"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="showResult">Show</v-btn>
        <div class="ma-3">
            Result: <span class="text-h6 red--text">{{ result }}<span>
        </div>
    </v-container>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>




Thank you, but the code you provided seems not working well. If you type "crossword" in the textfield, there is a glitch(jump) on the letter in the texfield. Also it gives "croundefinedsword" result.

@KeyboardCorporation My bad, the check for added character was ineffective. It's fixed now
